# Creating oracle Database instance

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration, oracle12c, impdp

We need to create a oracle database instance similar to customer environment. What are all the **parameters needs to be considered** other than similar version of software.

Like Character set, Multibyte Or Single Byte and other Database, Instance, Session level parameters which are to be considered.

If can import Dump Successfully into a Database instance with different NLS parameters, Will it be having any Side effects?

Answer (score 1):

Yes..It will. Lets say if your NLS_LANG parameter is set WE8ISO8859P1  and your customer is UTF8 , you wont be able to view the exact data.